# Is there a way to filter data when passing it in ModelForm and how can we edit them?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-forms

I'm creating a site to register students. So basically it is divided into 3 parts

```
1. A student register model which take the name, fathername, etc of student.
2. A student fee model which use foreignkey to get register student.
3. ModelForm for showing student fee model to enter data.
```

Now the problem if I want to fill a student fee of class 1 it shows all the student of other classes, but I want the student filter according to their classes and their name show and in front of them editable fee and pending fee form.

By some reach I got to know about `ModelForm` instance I wrote code for automatically add register students to student fee.

```
def student_fee(request):
    # add a selection field to a variable for filtering student_class below this.
    students = StudentRegister.objects.filter(student_class="1")
    ....
    for x in students:
        if not  StudentFee.objects.filter(student=x):
            StudentFee.objects.create(student=x, fee=0, pending_fee=0)
```

But for `instance` I have to know primary key of every student I can loop through them but it only get the last element.

models.py

```
class StudentRegister(models.Model):
    student_image    =      models.ImageField(upload_to="register_student", blank=True)
    student_class    =      models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STUDENT_CLASS, default="1")
    mobile_number    =      models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_name     =      models.CharField(max_length=50)
    father_name      =      models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mother_name      =      models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address          =      models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_fee      =      models.CharField(max_length=10, default="0")
    Date_Of_Birth    =      models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    admission_fee    =      models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Admission_date   =      models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    adhaar_no        =      models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s  class: %s" % (self.student_name, self.student_class)


class StudentFee(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(StudentRegister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fee = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pending_fee = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s " % (self.student)
```

forms.py

```
class StudentFeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentFee
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py(its messy sorry)

```
def student_fee(request):
    # add a selection field to a variable for filtering student_class below this.
    students = StudentRegister.objects.filter(student_class="1")
    real = StudentFee.objects.all()
    # student_form = StudentFeeForm(request.POST or None)
    student_form = StudentFeeForm(request.POST)#, instance=students)
    # print(dir(students))
    q = (students.get(pk=1))
    global list_student_pk
    list_student_pk = []
    for x in students:
        list_student_pk.append(x.pk)
    student_get_instance = StudentFeeForm(instance=q)
    # print(student_get_instance)

    # This thing done don't touch----------------------------------
    for x in students:
        if not StudentFee.objects.filter(student=x):
            StudentFee.objects.create(student=x, fee=0, pending_fee=0)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if student_form.is_valid():
            pass # this thing will done after the form problem solved.
    # till here ==========================================================

    return render(request, "student_fee_home.html", {"students": students, "real":real, "student_form":student_form, "list_student_pk":list_student_pk, "student_get_instance":student_get_instance})
```

I want that modelforms filter according to class.
Then the student fee model which already having register student(student name, fee, pending fee) can edit. So that it shows the student name and right in front of him a editable fee form and a pending fee form.

It is working right now like this showing all student of all classes, but I want that students name will show instead of selection field. In my knowledge only option to display names of student display names direct from models then use a form to take input of fee and pending fee then create it in models.

[image: NONE]

Comment: you're not telling us what's not working. Do you get an error? What behavior is not what you expect?

Comment: I want a modelform to show name of student(filter) and editable fee and pending fee form.

Answer (score 1):

djang0-filter will help you for filtering

```
pip install django-filter
```

## Model.py

```
    class Dispatcher(models.Model):
        _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE

        Individual = 'Individual'
        Company = 'Company'

        TYPES = [
            (Individual, 'Individual'),
            (Company, 'Company')
        ]
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                choices=TYPES,
                                default=Individual)
```

## Views.py

```
class DispatcherViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Dispatcher.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DispatcherSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ['type']
```

Comment: Okay filter problem solve but what if I have 60 students in a class it will be pain to select every student from selection field. How can I display their names and in front of them their fields?